# Pandas replace cell value for matching index between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DataFrame and I want to change the column value `'Final_Status'` for the matching fields:

```
#df_full:
EMG Final_Status
G05AT   Fail
G05AZ   Fail
O05AP   Pass
O05AZ   Fail
O15AP   Fail
O51AK   Fail
T05AP   Fail

#df_overwrite:
EMG Final_Status
G05AT   Pass
G05AZ   Pass

#final result:
#df_full:
EMG Final_Status
G05AT   Pass
G05AZ   Pass
O05AP   Pass
O05AZ   Fail
O15AP   Fail
O51AK   Fail
T05AP   Fail
```

I can do it by looping over all rows of the smaller df (df_overwrite) but loops make my code very slow. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the `Index` in pandas to force alignment, then you want `update`. You can `.reset_index()` if you want `'EMG'` back as a column.

```
df_full = df_full.set_index('EMG')
df_overwrite = df_overwrite.set_index('EMG')

df_full.update(df_overwrite, overwrite=True)
print(df_full)

      Final_Status
EMG               
G05AT         Pass
G05AZ         Pass
O05AP         Pass
O05AZ         Fail
O15AP         Fail
O51AK         Fail
T05AP         Fail
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `loc` here (assuming `EMG` is the index):

```
df_full.loc[df_overwrite.index] = df_overwrite
```

Comment: yes this also works, i had to modify a bit as i had more columns in df_full
df_full.loc[df_ow.index,'Final_Status'] = df_ow['Final_Status']